# C# serialization

Tags: c#, serialization

Hello I'm new to C# and I'm trying to serialize some data. I have a base class, which implements `ISerializable` and more subclasses that extend the base class. In my base class I wrote this:

```
protected BaseClass(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
{
    if (info == null)
        throw new System.ArgumentNullException("info");
 }

[SecurityPermission(SecurityAction.LinkDemand, Flags = SecurityPermissionFlag.SerializationFormatter)]
public virtual void GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
{
    if (info == null)
        throw new System.ArgumentNullException("info");
}
```

The problem is that when I run my program I get this error saying that my subclasses are not marked as serializable.
It's a big project. I bassicaly have a student class `class Student : ISerializable`, which is the base class, and I have `GraduateStudent : Student` and `PhDStudent : Student`. When I try to serialize a list of students( can be Student, GraduateStudent or PhDStudent) I get the error above. I have also tried to write like this `PhDStudent : Student,ISerializable`but no success

Comment: Then mark as `[Serializable]` :)

Comment: I've done that but I get the same error

Comment: We are only able to work with the information and example given. Please include that in the above example.

Comment: The message is clear enough: mark the subtypes. However: I ***strongly*** suggest to you that BinaryFormatter is going to hurt you here

Comment: I have written more info about it and updated the question

Comment: Hmm, no, projects that contain a class named Student are not yet big enough to become unmaintainable.

Answer (score 1):

If it is complaining that they aren't marked as serializable: *then do that*. ***Every*** type in the model (not just the base-type) must be marked `[Serializable]`. Actually, it is very rare that you would need to implement `ISerializable` here - I strongly suggest you don't do that, and just let the serializer worry about the fields until you know exactly what you are doing...

...because: when you are familiar with it, you'll probably find a lot of reasons to not blindly use `BinaryFormatter` - it can be horribly brittle and versions intolerant. Unless this is for a "needs to run once only" thing, I would strongly suggest alternatives like `XmlSerializer`, `DataContractSerializer`, json.net or protobuf-net.

Answer (score 0):

```
public abstract class BaseClass
{

}

public class Child1:BaseClass
{

}

public class Child2:BaseClass
{

}

public class SeriliazerTest
{
        // You have to define them here, otherwise they will not be found
        [XmlArrayItem(Type = typeof(Child1), ElementName = "Child1")]
        [XmlArrayItem(Type = typeof(Child2), ElementName = "Child2")] 
        public BaseClass[] Child {get;set;}
 }
```

Comment: ISerializable and the exception message suggest BinaryFormatter. Actually, this won't even work correctly in XnlSerializer - it is missing the XmlIncludeAttribute markers

Comment: Thanks @MarcGravell Sorry I do not saw that he want BinaryFormatter today is bad day for me I cant get any scores lol

Comment: Actually I never meant to get so complicated. I only want to serialize my list of students. In java I made this very easy but C# is giving me headaches

Comment: @user3043278 Then why you do not just use the XML serilizer very easy and human readable shall I post for you an example.

Comment: This is what I found on msdn so I thought it would work. Perhaps a simple example would help

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5170300/custom-xml-serialization-with-inheritance

Comment: as Marc said DataContractSerializer very easy: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13363806/data-contract-serialization-with-complex-types JSON might be also good for you coz you come from Java side

Comment: Thanks. I'll try to get into these new concepts